# How can I change the same state in multiple components and the value be accepted across all components

Tags: reactjs

So say if there is a function component and it has a variable const [num,setNum] = 0 and in it's return statment it's just 2 boxes of a positive and negative signs. I'm just wondering say if the user clicks the positive sign it takes you to the function addNum in a different file how could I in the other file have the ability to do setNum(num+1) and that would be the new value of the state.

Comment: The second file which your talking about it also a react component right ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. props drilling: passing the prop from parent to child
2. global state: state that is accessed across multiple components

The first approach is self-explanatory. The second one can be implemented [using Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or a third-party library such as [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/), [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)

If your project is not large then you probably won't need a third-party library and react-context is good enough for you.